# Unable to free drive under Linux

Tags: files, move

I have 8K remained on one of my drives:

```
> df
...
/dev/sdb1      3845577736  385295296 3264915224  11% /NAS/data
/dev/sdc1      3845577736 3650210512          8 100% /NAS/media
```

I take big folder and move it from `media` to `data`. After hundreds of gigabytes copied I have

```
> df
...
/dev/sdb1      3845577736  395182772 3255027748  11% /NAS/data
/dev/sdc1      3845577736 3650210512          8 100% /NAS/media
```

I.e. free space on target drive becomes less, while free space on source drive does not increase.

I am moving with Midnight Commander move command.

How to fix?

Comment: Has the move completed yet?  Some implementations of `mv` do not remove files until the complete tree has been copied when transferring between filesystems

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Fox in the comment to your question. The `mv` command doesn't remove the file(s) being moved until the copy has been completed when dealing with a `mv` between filesystems. Once the command has completed it should then reflect properly with the `df` command.

If it still didn't reflect properly after the command had completed successfully I would recommend a `fsck` on the filesystem that is showing incorrectly. (And of course, make sure you have a backup just in case.)